# Add custom roles to a group using Google API

Tags: google-admin-sdk

From group setting we can create new custom roles to be add to the built-in ones (OWNER, MANAGER and MEMBER), and we can assign those custom roles to any member of the group.

Using the Directory API, is there any way to add a custom role? and get all roles assigned to a member including those custom roles?

Thank you

Comment: Have you read https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/#Groups?

Comment: Tks, and yes I did, I'm still looking if it's possible in one of those APIs: Admin Settings API, Groups Settings API, Directory API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I checked, this is still not possible. You can take a look at some pages like the [Members: Update](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/update) info, and you'll see that the `role` parameter still only accepts the three allowed values you mentioned.